# Sub-array dimensions 1-by-1-by-N

Tags: matlab

Let's say I have a 3-dimensional array `A = rand(3, 4, 5);` and I want to extract a vector `A(1,1,:)`. If I write it like this, the output is a 3D array of size `[1 1 5]` instead of a plain vector of size `[1 5]`. This doesn't allow me, for example, to assign it to another sub-array `B(1,:)` (results in "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch"). What is the best way to extract the vector without preserving the original dimensions?
I can think of 2 approaches:

- Calculate linear indexes of the desired elements instead of using subscripts:

  ```
  targetInds = 1:5;
  fixedInds = repmat(1,size(targetInds));
  inds = sub2ind(size(A), fixedInds, fixedInds, targetInds);
  size(A(inds))

  ans =
       1     5
  ```
- Use `reshape`:

  ```
  subA = reshape(A(1,1,:),1,size(A,3));
  size(subA)

  ans =
       1     5
  ```

The second approach seems easier but I guess it's less efficient, and both of them require extra code. Is there a more straightforward way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squeeze will do the same thing, but works for any dimension.
http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html

```
>> b=squeeze(A(1,1,:));
>> size(b)
ans =
     5     1
```

I realise, it is not the exact same thing. squeeze returns a column vector, whil the other answer produces a row vector. Nevertheless B(1,:) = b; works.

Comment: Perfect! That's the term I couldn't find: singleton dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html):

> `B = permute(A,order)` rearranges the dimensions of A so that they are in the order specified by the vector order. B has the same values of A but the order of the subscripts needed to access any particular element is rearranged as specified by order. All the elements of order must be unique, real, positive, integer values.

```
>> subA = permute(A, [1 3 2]);
>> size(subA)
ans = 

    1    5
```